# drawing custom line chart and column chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I need to make line charts and column charts for cricket run rate, wickets etc. and due to some extra requirement I am unable to use the libraries available on internet like google charts, highchart etc.

Some of the requirements are:

- show more than 1 circle on line/column chart if more than 1 wickets falls in an over, something like the image below
- different color of each bar

[image: Sample bar graph]

[image: Sample line graph]

I have searched on google but couldnt find any ready to use libraries like this
and before I decide to draw custom charts I wanted to confirm if there is any library available where I can do these custom changes and if not then I need suggestion if I can draw them in HTML5 or what do you think would be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

It sound like you want to take a look at [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/). I've used it on several occasions, and it's a good tool for making charts with HTML5 and JavaScript. It gives you a wide variety of different charts to choose from without having to custom code a whole bunch of stuff. And they look nice as well.

The examples in the [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) are very descriptive, and the default example includes a bar-chart that has alternating colors, matching that of your example pictures.